# expectation maximization algorithm matlab out of memory error

Tags: matlab, machine-learning, expectation-maximization

I am implementing Expectation Maximization algorithm in matlab. Algorithm is operating on 214096 x 2 data matrix and While computing probabilities, there is multiplication of ( 214096 x 2 ) * (2 x 2) * ( 2 x 214096 ) matrices, which is resulting in error of out of memory in matlab. Is there a way to fix this problem?

[Equation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gka33.jpg)

Matlab Code:

```
          enter image description here  D = size(X,2); % dimension
            N = size(X,1); % number of samples
            K = 4; % number of Gaussian Mixture components ( Also number of clusters )

            % Initialization
            p = [0.2, 0.3, 0.2, 0.3]; % arbitrary pi, probabilities of clusters, apriori probability of cluster
            [idx,mu] = kmeans(X,K); % initial means of the components, theta is mu and variance

            % compute the covariance of the components
            sigma = zeros(D,D,K);
            for k = 1:K
                tempmat = X(idx==k,:);
                sigma(:,:,k) = cov(tempmat);  % Sigma j
                sigma_det(k) = det(sigma(:,:,k));
            end

            % calculate x-mu
            for k=1: K
                            check=length( X(idx == k,1))
                            for  lidx = 1: length( X(idx == k,1))

                                cidx = find( idx == k) ;
                                Xmu(cidx(lidx),:) = X(cidx(lidx),:) - mu(k,:); %( x-mu ) calculation on cluster level
                            end
            end


            % compute P(Cj|x; theta(t)), and take log to simplified calculation

            %Eq 14.14 denominator 
            denom = 0;
            for k=1:K
                calc_sigma_1_2 = sigma_det(k)^(-1/2);
                calc_x_mu = Xmu(idx == k,:);
                calc_sigma_inv = inv(sigma(:,:,k)); 
                calc_x_mu_tran = calc_x_mu.';
                factor = calc_sigma_1_2 * exp (-1/2 * calc_x_mu * calc_sigma_inv * calc_x_mu_tran  ) * p(k);

                denom = denom + factor;
            end


            for k =1:K 
                calc_sigma_1_2 = sigma_det(k)^(-1/2);
                calc_x_mu = Xmu(idx == k,:);
                calc_sigma_inv = inv(sigma(:,:,k)); 
                calc_x_mu_tran = calc_x_mu.';
                factor = calc_sigma_1_2 * exp (-1/2 * calc_x_mu_tran * calc_sigma_inv * calc_x_mu ) * p(k);

                pdf(k) = factor/denom;
            end

            %%%% Equation 14.14 ends
```

Comment: is 214096 number of dimensions/features?

Comment: 214096 is number of observations in each of 2 dimensions

Comment: When in EM algorithm you get a matrix of N^2 elements? it does not seem correct. Why would you need a Gramian?

Comment: I might have wrong understanding of algorithm then, i am using P(Cj | x : theta(t) ) = det(sigma)^-1/2 * exp ( -1/2 (x - mu).' * Inv(sigma) * (x-mu) / ( xxxx)  to compute conditional probabilities in Expectation step. sigma is covariance matrix of (214096 x 2) data, mu is first iteration clusters mean and x is data sample. x-mu in my case is resulting in same 214096 x 2 matrix. Is this correct?

Comment: isn't this point wise? this does not look like a valid equation for x being a matrix, it looks like a valid one for per-vector only (thus x has to be 1x2), otherwise as a result of this operation you would get matrix N x N, which does not represent any reasonable probabilistic object, you want to get a number

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you tried to apply vector based equation by simply substituting vector for matrix, this is not how it works

```
(x - mu).' * Inv(sigma) * (x-mu)
```

is supposed to be **mahalanobis** norm of (x-mu), and you want to obtain this value per each row of matrix X, thus

```
(X - mu).' * Inv(sigma) =: A <- this is ok, this results in N x d matrix
```

and now you have to do **point-wise** multiplication of A with (X - mu), not a dot product, and finally sum over second axis (columns), this way you end up with `N` element vector, each containing a mahalanobis norm of corresponding row from X.

Comment: Thanks a lot @lejlot, i m fixing this